# How should I repair a loose marble door sill?

Tags: bathroom, marble

My bathroom door has a marble door sill, which turns out not to be affixed to anything, so that I can move it freely. (See photos.) I imagine that I ought to fix this. What should I use?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mix up some thinset mortar and spread out out evenly and then place the door sill on top... Try to even out the area between the sill and the tile as it looks uneven from the photo. The sill can be a little bit slanted to even off the edges of the tile and wood floors. You can fill in any cracks or spaces with the thinset too.

Comment: You will probably need to do some doorframe trim disassembly to get access to remove the marble so you can do this right. You want to set it into a bed of mortar (as Jack describes), not stuff some in around the edges. You may need to remove any loose or degraded mortar already in the space, or simply to make space for new mortar. You may also want to trim a floorboard if it is actually sitting on top of the hardwood, as it appears to be. These are very satisfying to get done right.

Comment: And easy on your feet.